# How to block move in Windows 8 Store App

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

I'm developping a public application (Screen in a public place) with Windows 8.
My question : is it possible to block the "Close Gesture" by dragging the top of the apps ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Kiosk Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx). This can enable you to have a [single Windows Store Application experience](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ff9a4a7-530c-425a-98dd-1d3bf6af18d8/how-i-can-config-user-kiosk-mode-in-windows-81-preview?forum=w81previtpro) on your device.